# Access nodelet_manager when playing bagfile

Tags: ros, bagfile, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a program that depends on the pointcloud_to_laserscan nodelet code. For normal access with real data, I use the following launch code:

I have some bagfiles for which I recorded the transformation frame, and the /robot/camera2/depth_registered/points topic. The actual rosbag command was:

rosbag record /robot/camera2/rgb/image_rect /robot/camera2/rgb/image_rect_color /robot/camera2/depth_registered/points /tf /robot_tf/camera2_rgb_optical_frame /robot_tf/camera2_rgb_frame /robot_tf/camera2_depth_frame /robot_tf/camera2/depth_optical_frame /robot_tf/base_link

But while I can play and view all of the recorded data and topics in rviz with no problems, running the CloudToScan routine doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't generate any topics, but it doesn't throw any errors either... at least not that I can tell. I've also checked (rosrun tf view_frames), and the specified transformation space exists (/robot_tf/camera2_depth_frame). So I don't know what's going on.

My best guess is it has something to do with the nodelet manager mentioned in the CloudScan launch code (robot_camera2_nodelet_manager). Do I need to record the nodelet manager when recording the bagfile? Is that possible? Obviously, I could record the CloudScan topic, but I'm hoping to figure out the right parameters for the system, rather than having to re-record all the time.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55946/access-nodelet_manager-when-playing-bagfile/) by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer (as explained to me by a co-worker that saw my post) is to launch a nodelet manager:

... and change the nodelet manager name in the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) with karma: 100 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0